# How to get latestReply in a Channel without an expensive call?

Tags: laravel

A Channel has Threads which has a latestReply. I'm trying to show the most recent reply next to the channel.

I have something that works but is a 620ms call...

Here is my current code:

```
public function latestReply()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(Reply::class, Thread::class, 'channel_id', 'thread_id', 'id', 'id')->latest();
}
```

Then I iterate through the Channels and call `$channel->latestReply->created_at`. This is definitely not optimal for me as it significantly slows down the load time.

Can anyone please let me know of a better way to get the latest Reply within a Channel? I think I have an idea and will be trying to figure it out in the meantime.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried eager loading that relation `Channel::with('latestReply')`?

Comment: hi yes i did, it's still very slow

Answer (score 1):

How about you add a new `hasOne` with your own implementation with joins rather than the default queries executed by laravel

```
class Channel extends Model
{
    //.. other stuff
    // Approach 1 with joins
    public function latestReply()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Thread::class, 'channel_id')
                    ->join('replies as a', 'threads.id', '=', 'a.thread_id')
                    ->leftJoin('replies as a1', function ($join) {
                        $join->on('a.thread_id', '=', 'a1.thread_id')
                             ->whereRaw(DB::raw('a.created_at < a1.created_at'));
                       })
                    ->whereNull('a1.thread_id')
                    ->select('a.*', 'channel_id');
    }
    // Approach 2 with whereExists
    public function reply()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Thread::class, 'channel_id')
                    ->join('replies as a', 'threads.id', '=', 'a.thread_id')
                    ->whereExists(function ($query) {
                       $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                             ->from('replies as b')
                             ->whereRaw(DB::raw('a.thread_id = b.thread_id'))
                             ->havingRaw('max(b.created_at) = a.created_at')
                             ;
                   })->select('a.*', 'channel_id');
    }
}
```

And then use eager loading for latest reply

```
$channels = Channel::with(['latestReply','recentReply'])->get();
```

Also a composite index on replies (thread_id,created_at) will be good to have to improve performance of above query

[DEMO](https://implode.io/CqDW98)

Comment: i would have never thought of that solution, but it looks like the query took about 4 about secs to load -- which is 3.3 secs longer than the solution in the OP

Comment: @user123 If you already have proper indexes in place then it shouldn't be taking that much time, I have tried to add another variation with `whereExists` have a look at updated answer

Comment: Thanks I will definitely look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok there is a workaround in which I don't have to call the latestReply relationship at all.

In the Thread model:

```
protected $touches = ['channel'];
```

In the Reply model:

```
protected $touches = ['thread'];
```

When you iterate through the channels, simply call $channel->updated_at.

Then when you "edit" a reply: use these line of code to update it so that it doesn't touch the Channel model timestamp upon an edit:

```
    $time = $reply->thread->channel->updated_at;

    $reply->update([
        'body' => request('body')
    ]);

    \DB::table('channels')->where(['id' => $reply->thread->channel->id])->update(['updated_at' => $time]);
```

And do the same for when you update a thread:

```
    $time = $thread->channel->updated_at;
    
    $thread->update([
        'title' => request('title'),
        'body' => request('body'),
    ]);

    \DB::table('threads')->where(['id' => $thread->channel->id])->update(['updated_at' => $time]);
```